# enquirerの使い方について(npmの作成)

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

#### 説明

現在JavaScriptを学習中で、自作npmを作成しています。
npmの内容としましては、5問連続で問題に答えてもらい、5問中4問以上あっていたらクリアという仕様にしたいと思っております。

#### 実行環境

- macOS Big Sur バージョン11.6
- npm 7.21.1
- node 16.9.0

#### やりたいこと

enquirerを使用して、5問連続でクイズが出題できるようにしたいです。
こちらの記事を参考にして作成しております。
https://github.com/enquirer/enquirer#quiz-prompt

#### やってみたこと

`for...of`を使用してみたが、期待の結果とはならなかったです。

```js
// main.js

const data = require('./data')
const { Quiz } = require('enquirer')
// 0~10の間で得たい場合は、11を指定
const randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)

class SetQuiz {
  introduce () {
    console.log('関西の難読地名クイズを行います。')
  }

  async set () {
    const answer = await new Quiz(data.questions[randomNumber]).run()
    if (answer.correct) {
      console.log('正解! すごい!')
    } else {
      console.log(`残念、不正解。 答えは... 「${answer.correctAnswer}」`)
    }
    console.log('お疲れさま')
  }

  async main () {
    this.introduce()
    this.set()
  }
}
for (let step = 0; step < 2; step++) {
  const quiz = new SetQuiz()
  quiz.main()
}
```

```js
// data.js

const questions = [
  {
    name: 'name',
    message: '「枚方」の読み方を教えて',
    choices: ['まいかた', 'まかた', 'まいほう', 'ひらかた'],
    correctChoice: 3
  },
  {
    name: 'name',
    message: '「放出」の読み方を教えて',
    choices: ['はなた', 'はなてん', 'ほうしゅつ', 'ほうで'],
    correctChoice: 1
  },
  {
    name: 'name',
    message: '「住道」の読み方を教えて',
    choices: ['じゅうどう', 'すみみち', 'すみのみち', 'すみのどう'],
    correctChoice: 3
  }
]
module.exports = {
  questions
}
```

[image: 失敗した画像]
[image: 失敗した画像]

#### 現状

1問は出題することができていて、正解か不正解かも判定できている
[image: 現在の状況画像]
[image: 現在の状況画像]

#### 現状のコード

```js
// main.js

const data = require('./data')
const { Quiz } = require('enquirer')
// 0~10の間で得たい場合は、11を指定
const randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)

class SetQuiz {
  introduce () {
    console.log('関西の難読地名クイズを行います。')
  }

  async set () {
    const answer = await new Quiz(data.questions[randomNumber]).run()
    if (answer.correct) {
      console.log('正解! すごい!')
    } else {
      console.log(`残念、不正解。 答えは... 「${answer.correctAnswer}」`)
    }
    console.log('お疲れさま')
  }

  async main () {
    this.introduce()
    this.set()
  }
}
const quiz = new SetQuiz()
quiz.main()
```

```js
// data.js

const questions = [
  {
    name: 'name',
    message: '「枚方」の読み方を教えて',
    choices: ['まいかた', 'まかた', 'まいほう', 'ひらかた'],
    correctChoice: 3
  },
  {
    name: 'name',
    message: '「放出」の読み方を教えて',
    choices: ['はなた', 'はなてん', 'ほうしゅつ', 'ほうで'],
    correctChoice: 1
  },
  {
    name: 'name',
    message: '「住道」の読み方を教えて',
    choices: ['じゅうどう', 'すみみち', 'すみのみち', 'すみのどう'],
    correctChoice: 3
  }
]

module.exports = {
  questions
}
```

以上のような状況となっております。
少しでもアドバイスいただけたら幸いです。
よろしくお願い致します‍♂️

Answer (score -1, accepted):

自己解決しました！‍♂️
作りたいものを作ることができました。

Comment: スタック・オーバーフローでは、自己回答も歓迎しています。次この質問を見に来た方のために、ぜひどうやって解決したのかもこの回答に含めるようにしてみてください。回答は後からでも [edit] できます！